# How to take href value of a current HTML?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have tried to put the name of the HTML file in a  tag and take the href value using the id of it, but it does not work. I need to take the current HTML file name using JavaScript or jQuery.

```
document.getElementById("currentHTML").getAttribute("href"); //returns: Cannot read property 'getAttribute' of null
```

Comment: What is the relative HTML code example to go with that handling?

Comment: Either the id is wrong or you are looking for it before it exists. If the duplicate doesn't solve the issue then add enough  html to reproduce the problem

Comment: @charlietfl  Yes, I was looking for it before it existed, thank You!

Comment: try to add defer properties to your script tag => <script defer></script>  like this

Comment: Why does this deserve an upvote is beyond me; just saying.